# RxJS 6 conditionally pipe an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an existing function which does some amount of work calling HTTP endpoints that takes care of managing some logic in my Angular component.  A requirement comes in so that in a certain instance we need to all of the existing logic to be called, but also another HTTP call to be made.  Below is an annotated version of my attempt.

```
public resolveComponent(action: string) {
        //if called with no parameters, don't do anything
        //otherwise, call one of the two endpoints.     
        let preAction = (x: any) => {
            if (action === "replay") {
                return this.remediationService
                           .replayRemediation(this.workflow.Id);
            }
            else if (action === "remove") {
                return this.remediationService
                           .removeRemediation(this.workflow.Id);
            }
            else {
                return of([]);
            }
        }

        this.remediationService
            .resolveComponent(component)
            .pipe(
                //the line below was what I added after new requirement
                mergeMap(preAction),
                mergeMap(x => {
                    //grabs updated data from server
                    return this.remediationService.remediationComponent(component.Id);
                })
            )
            .subscribe((x: SomeModel) => {
                    //logic happens
                });
}
```

This performs the work as expected, but is this the best way to go about conditionally chaining observables?

Comment: You can try switchMap to return different observables based on condition

Comment: he wont use switchmap because he is waiting for a response, exhaustmap would be a better choice. Back to topic: i think its a legit way to do it like you do

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Use the new *iif* rxjs operator. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/conditional/iif
Thanks to @moslem-shahsavan and Rx team )

You can add your own `pipeIf`:

```
import { from, Observable, of, NEVER } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

from([10, 11, 12, 13])
  .pipe(
    map(x => x + 10),
    pipeIf(x => x > 21,
      filter(x => x > 22),
      map(x => x + 100)
    ),
)
  .subscribe(console.log);

function pipeIf(predicate, ...pipes) {
  return function (source) {
    return source.pipe(
      mergeMap(value => predicate(value) ? of(value).pipe(...pipes) : of(value))
    )
  }
}

// 20
// 21
// 123
```

Comment: There's an issue with spreading arguments in pipe. Learn more: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3989

Comment: @Buggy: Can you add typescript types? Also, is spreading `...pipes` twice correct? Plus I think this does not work with time based operators.

Answer (score 33):

Use `iif` rxjs.

`iif` accepts a condition function and two Observables. When

- an Observable returned by the operator is subscribed, condition function will be called.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/conditional/iif

Comment: I think this should be accepted as the answer. The use of `iif()` lets you conditionally include an observable to your subscription when you pass only one observable to the `iff()` operator. See a clear example in "Control an access to an Observable" at https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif

Answer (score 13):

[`iif`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) can conditionally write observables:

- `iif(() => cond, obs1, obs2)` = `cond ? obs1 : obs2`
- `iif(() => cond, obs1)` = `cond ? obs1 : EMPTY`

But `iif` is not for operators. If you want to conditionally write operators in `.pipe()`, use:

```js
cond ? delay(1000) : interval(500)
```

For empty operators, use [`identity`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/identity):

```js
import { identity } from 'rxjs'
cond ? delay(1000) : identity
```

Where `identity` is actually `x => x`

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple `when` operator with Typescript support:

```
function when<V>(condition: (val: V) => boolean, execute: (source: Observable<V>) => Observable<V>) {
    return (source: Observable<V>) => source.pipe(concatMap((val) => (condition(val) ? execute(of(val)) : of(val))));
}
```

With the following usage example:

```
of({ success: false }).pipe(
    tap((value) => console.log('success:', value.success)),
    when((value) => !value.success,
        (source) => source.pipe(
            tap(() => console.log('not success')),
            delay(1000)
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could probably just use `merge()` (or `concat()` if you need the streams to be sequential) instead of two `mergeMap()` since you don't seem to need the output of your new streams to be the input of your existing stream:

```
const replayObservable = of("Has been Replayed");
const removeObservable = of("Has been Removed");
const existingObservable = of(
  "Finally, do what you already did before the CR."
);
const resolveComponent = (action?: string) => {
  const newSource = of();
  const targetWithoutNull = newSource.pipe(
    merge(
      iif(
        () => !!action,
        iif(() => action == "replay", replayObservable, removeObservable)
      ),
      existingObservable
    )
  );
  targetWithoutNull.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
};

resolveComponent("replay");
resolveComponent("remove");
resolveComponent();
```

Note that the first `iif()` has only 2 parameters. `iif()` will complete the stream if the condition points to an undefined parameter so in this case, only the existingObservable will be subscribed to.

See this running: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-7ztk16

Answer (score -2):

This one worked for me,

```
declare module "rxjs" {
    interface Observable<T> {
      pipeIf(validExpression:boolean, truePipe:Array<UnaryFunction<T,T>>, falsePipe:Array<UnaryFunction<T,T>>): Observable<T>
    }
  }

  Observable.prototype.pipeIf = function(validExpression:boolean, truePipe:Array<OperatorFunction<any,any>>, falsePipe:Array<OperatorFunction<any,any>>):Observable<any>{
    return validExpression ? this.pipe.apply(this,truePipe) : this.pipe.apply(this, falsePipe)
  }
```